# How to pass value from javascript function to django view

Tags: javascript, django, view

my question is, what´s the better way to pass a value from a javascript function to django view.

I have a template where I get a value through a javascript function, and I want to pass that value to a django view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is pretty general, but here's one way of doing it.  You could use jQuery to make your AJAX call like this:

```
        $.ajax({type: 'POST',
                url: '/fetch_data/',                            // some data url
                data: {param: 'hello', another_param: 5},       // some params  
                success: function (response) {                  // callback
                    if (response.result === 'OK') {
                        if (response.data && typeof(response.data) === 'object') {
                            // do something with the successful response.data
                            // e.g. response.data can be a JSON object
                        }
                    } else {
                        // handle an unsuccessful response
                    }
                }
               });
```

And your Django view would be something like this:

```
def fetch_data(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        # extract your params (also, remember to validate them)
        param = request.POST.get('param', None)
        another_param = request.POST.get('another param', None)

        # construct your JSON response by calling a data method from elsewhere
        items, summary = build_my_response(param, another_param)

        return JsonResponse({'result': 'OK', 'data': {'items': items, 'summary': summary}})
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

Many details are obviously omitted here, but you can use this as a guideline.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways here:

1. Ajax request to your view
2. Redirect user to new URL where your value is query parametr

Comment: have you any example of using ajax please? i´m new

Comment: @Jmint: That is outwith the scope of this question (and this site to be honest). If you're familiar with jquery, start at http://www.sitepoint.com/ajax-jquery/ for learning jquery AJAX. Google will help you find tutorials for AJAX with vanilla javascript